# is a .jsp file intended to be rendered in a browser like a .html file?

Tags: java, jsp, apache2, mod-jk

I have a hello.war file (an example file from GlassFish website), and I'm trying to access it from a browser. (this file can be downloaded from [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/geyvr/index.html))

I can deploy this war file to GlassFish server, and access it fine from:

```
www.mydomain.com:8080/hello/
```

However, I want to access it from:

```
www.mydomain.com/glassfish-test/hello/
```

So to do that I modified the httpd.conf file (VirtualHost section) with this line (and restart Apache):

```
JkMount /glassfish-test/* worker1
```

And placed the hello.war file into ~/public_html/glassfish-test/ directory. Then I unzipped it using tar xvf and I see an index.jsp file among other things (located in the glassfish-test directory). If I set up GlassFish with Apache and mod_jk correctly, what is the URL I would need to set the browser to in order to view the hello.war application?

Would it be...

```
www.mydomain.com/glassfish-test/hello/
www.mydomain.com/glassfish-test/index.jsp
www.mydomain.com/glassfish-test/WEB-INF/???
```

I never worked with a .jsp or war file before. Any comments much appreciated.

Comment: Clients may not access anything under WEB-INF directly. We have no idea where your `index.jsp` file is, if it's defined as a welcome file, etc., so there's no real way to answer the question, though.

Comment: The index.jsp file is located in ~/public_html/glassfish-test/ directory. I added a link in the post above to download the hello.war file. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Apache application server is listening on port 8080. Since you want to access the page by omitting the ":8080" in the hostname, then you need to configure Apache to listen on the default HTTP port, which is port 80.

Comment: Thanks Bob, when you say Apache application server, do you mean GlassFish? How to configure it to listen on port 80? My httpd.conf file has a Listen 0.0.0.0:80 line of code, as well as a <VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80> section that refers to port 80, and I include the JkMount statement above. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Seems to be a bug issue with GlassFish 3.1.1  http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17068?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel